# Get the path of the current TTY in Python

Tags: python, command-line

How do you get the device path for the current TTY?

Python has `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `os.ttyname` but you cannot pass either of the formers to the latter because it requires a file descriptor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `sys.stdout.fileno` to `os.ttyname`:

```
In [3]: os.ttyname(sys.stdout.fileno())
Out[3]: '/dev/pts/24'
```

Comment: You are correct! Oddly, `sys.stdout` does not have a `fileno` method in bpython, though it does in python and ipython. I do all my REPL Driven Development in bpython and therefore missed it.

Comment: `sys.stdout.fileno` should return 1 unless the previous code changed it to something funky

Answer (score 1):

This may have portability issues, but in most Unix-like environments `/dev/stdout` refers to the current terminal and is unique to each connection [windows, tabs, ssh, etc.] you have open. Given those assumptions you can use:

```
with open('/dev/stdout') as fd:
    tty_path = os.ttyname(fd.fileno())
```